# Load div from another page within an AJAX loaded page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery address to enable loading specific content from other pages
and to change the URL in the address bar.

I'm working on a little Social Network alike website, so I'm reading out the IDs
of the `posts` table of my MySQL database via PHP. I want to use the possibilities of jQuery and AJAX to read everything out dynamically.

I found out, that I have to use `live()` (which turned out to be old), `delegate()` (which
also turned out to be old in 1.7.1) or `on()` (which turns out to be the best possibility
to make events work inside of dynamically loaded content via jQuery + AJAX).

I also read somewhere, that I can't use `load()` or `get()` to load new content from another
page inside of an already loaded content, because it doesn't "bubble" (I don't even know
what that means).

What do I have to do to load new content within an AJAX loaded page?

Here's a snippet I tried to work with (included on the loaded page):

```
<?php 
    if(exist('`posts`')) {
        $load = mysql_query('SELECT `id` FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($load)) {
?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('body').on('body', 'load', function() {
                    $.get('getpost.php', { pid: <?= $row->id ?> }, function (data) {
                        $('#posts').html($('#post_<?= $row->id ?>', data).html()).show();
                    });
                    $('#posts').off('load');
                });
            </script>
<?php
        }
    }
    else {
?>
    <div align="center">No posts yet.</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

getpost.php is my file from which I can get the `div_$row->id` so that it appears on the start page.

PLUS (Just adding for your knowledge) I want the content to load the content without
a mouseover, click or blur event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I the only one who thinks that this approach is completely wrong? You're making an ajax request for each post, this could end up in making way too much requests, heavily slowing down the loading time. I can't see any reason why you don't want to directly write the posts' HTML inside the PHP while loop.

Comment: Sounds logic and like a better solution. Did it like you told me. Thanks! :-)

Comment: You probably want to chunk N blocks in the PHP code, and then use ajax to load the next chunk of N blocks when the user scrolls to the end of the visible content, or clicks on the "next" button, or whatever your UI provides.  It's reasonable for the PHP code to only generate roughly a page worth of content at a time, and then generate more in response to user activity.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use ".live()" if you want a particular event mapping to be applied dynamically to any new DOM elements which match its selector.  Alternatively, you can attach the behavior to each chunk of content loaded.

Write and develop your ajax load independently of your DB lookup to make things simpler.  The following snippet triggers another ajax call after each element loads.

```
<?php
$id = 'div'.mt_rand();
$counter = isset($_REQUEST['counter']) ? $_REQUEST['counter'] : 0;
$next = $counter + 1;
echo <<<END
<div id="{$id}">{$counter}
<script>
$(function() {
   $.ajax('/url?counter={$next}', function(html) {
       $(html).appendTo($('#{$id}').parent()); // or whatever your favorite method is for adding a sibling
   });
});
</script>
</div>
END;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Solution (find above). Though your solution might be really helpful for other parts of my website. So thanks a lot!